# Is there an event from Backbone.js Model fired when the Collection re-fetched

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have a Backbone Collection initialized by running collection.fetch() method, and then after a while, I asked the collection to fetch again in order to refresh the models. so, is there any event from Model fired that I can subscribe from View in order to remove/update the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a specific "the collection has been refetched" event but you don't need one. [`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) resets the collection:

> **fetch** `collection.fetch([options])`
>   [...]
>   When the model data returns from the server, the collection will *reset*.

And [`reset`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset) triggers a `"reset"` event:

> **reset** `collection.reset(models, [options])`
>   [...]
>   Use **reset** to replace a collection with a new list of models (or attribute hashes), triggering a single `"reset"` event at the end.

So just listen for `"reset"` events from the collection and re-render the view when you get one.

---

The behavior of `fetch` changed in Backbone 1.0, from the [ChangeLog](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog):

> - Renamed Collection's "update" to *set*, for parallelism with the similar `model.set()`, and contrast with *reset*. It's now the default updating mechanism after a *fetch*. If you'd like to continue using "reset", pass `{reset: true}`.

And if we look at [`set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-set):

> **set** `collection.set(models, [options])`
>
> The set method performs a "smart" update of the collection with the passed list of models. If a model in the list isn't yet in the collection it will be added; if the model is already in the collection its attributes will be merged; and if the collection contains any models that aren't present in the list, they'll be removed. All of the appropriate `"add"`, `"remove"`, and `"change"` events are fired as this happens.

So you can say `collection.fetch({ reset: true })` if you want to keep using the `"reset"` event or you can `collection.fetch()` and listen for individual `"add"`, `"remove"`, and `"change"` events.

Comment: I don't think so. The fetch will create new models and the old ones will simply be forgotten (not destroyed) so there won't be any model events, just the single collection event.

Comment: OK, is it free to fetch for multiple times? I am worrying whether it will cause memory problem or not.

Comment: Should be fine as long as you don't have any stray references to the models in the collection. So listen to the collection ([which forwards events on its models](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection)) and you should be fine.

Comment: Reset doesn't always appear to fire.

Comment: @NathanC.Tresch: Backbone 1.0 changed how `fetch` works, it now ["uses *set* to (intelligently) merge the fetched models, unless you pass `{reset: true}`, in which case the collection will be (efficiently) reset."](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch). So you can use the `reset:true` option or listen for individual `"add"` or `"remove"` events. You might also notice that 1.0 came out *after* this answer.

Comment: @muistooshort I am indeed passing reset:true, but it's still not triggering.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.